# Repeating Json data from AngularJS inside Polymer element

Tags: angularjs, polymer-1.0

I am having trouble repeating the json fethched data from angularjs inside the polymer web-element.

**1. angularjs Controller :**

```
app.controller('SubjectController', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
     $http.get('api2.json').success(function(data){
        $scope.values = data.subjects;
        $scope.params = $routeParams.id;
     });   
 })
```

**2.polymer 1.0 web element**

```
<dom-module id="subject-list">
  <template is="dom-bind">
    {{values}}
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{values.name}}">
        <paper-card>
          <div class="card-content">
            <span id="heading">{{item.name}}</span><span class="class"><span>{{item.total}}</span><span> questions</span></span>
          </div>
        </paper-card>

    </template>
  </template>

<script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'subject-list'
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

so far up to here if I display only the **JSON** data like by using {{values}} 
[image: json data showing only by using {{values}}]
then it is shown successfully in the page but when I try it to repeat using **dom-repeat** then it shows only blank page. Please help me where i get missed.
thank you ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it solved now by removing upper main  tag

```
<dom-module id="subject-list">
  <!-- <template is="dom-bind"> -->
    {{values}}
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{values.name}}">
        <paper-card>
          <div class="card-content">
            <span id="heading">{{item.name}}</span><span class="class"><span>{{item.total}}</span><span> questions</span></span>
          </div>
        </paper-card>

    </template>
  <!--</template> -->

<script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'subject-list'
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```